# Could not find a custom installed gem during runtime

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rhel8

On rhel8, I built and installed a custom gem `test1`.

```
$ gem build test1.gemspec
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: test1
  Version: 0.0.1
  File: test1-0.0.1.gem
$ gem install test1-0.0.1.gem
Successfully installed test1-0.0.1
1 gem installed
# check if gem is installed. All gems are installed in this path
$ gem which test1
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/test1-0.0.1/lib/test1.rb
```

Now in another custom gem I build, the gemspec file looks like this:

```
# in test2.gemspec file
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "test2"
  ...

  spec.add_runtime_dependency "test1", "0.0.1"
  ...
end
```

When I try to go install test2 gem it fails and says it could not find the test1 gem which is already installed. This problem started happening on rhel8. I tested on debian and alpine and it had no issues finding and installing the gem.

```
$ gem build test2.gemspec
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: test2
  Version: 0.0.1
  File: test2-0.0.1.gem
$ gem install test2-0.0.1.gem
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'test1' (= 0.0.1) in any repository
```

If I change to `add_development_dependency`, it builds and installs the gem. The image works as expected and has no issues. Does anyone know why its not able to find the gem when I add `add_runtime_dependency`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a private gem that requires another private gem, you will need to define the dependency gem in both the `gemspec` and the `Gemfile`, while providing the actual source in the `Gemfile`.

For example, we are using [GemFury](https://gemfury.com/) to host private gems, and then in any other gem that needs this private gem, we do this:

```rb
# Gemfile
source 'https://gem.fury.io/your-user/' do
  gem 'your-gem'
end

gemspec


# your-gem.gemspec
s.add_runtime_dependency 'your-gem', '0.0.1'
```

Comment: I still run into the same issue. It seems like gem only checks the current directory for local gems where it should be checking the gem paths `/usr/local/share/gems` (defined in the `gem envir`). If I build both gems from the root (e.g. `gem build path/to/dir/test1.gemspec`) it works.